# Blender 2.8 Inflating a balloon

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

I'm trying to inflate a balloon for an animation. I would know how to do this in Maya with nCloth as there is an option for air pressure and pump rate. Is there anything similar to that functionality in Blender 2.8 or how to get this done using Cloth or Soft Body simulation?

I found this solution here [using Soft Bodies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/scaling-a-soft-body-object)

But that is not quite what I'm looking for since this is more scaling than inflating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Related (but might not be quite what you're looking for) : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81458/29586. Also : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/112727/29586

Comment: This is perhaps what you are looking for:
https://developer.blender.org/T30941 old version:
https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-cloth-simulator-air-pressure-enhancement/538395